# CodeIgniter: js files do not work properly in all pages using base_url()

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am developing an application using CodeIgniter.
All the css and js files are in a folder called assets placed in the main root:

**Application**
**system**
**assets**
**...**

This is the `.htacess` file in the main root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/tickets

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In the `config.php` file I set following:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/projects/tickets/";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In the `autoload.php` file I set following:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html','url');
```

In the view `footer.php` I have different scripts like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo
base_url('assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js');?>"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is a simple controller named `ticket.php`:

```
public function index() {

    $this->load->view('structure/head');
    $this->load->view('structure/header');
    $this->load->view('structure/main-navigation');
    $this->load->view('structure/content');
    $this->load->view('structure/side-bar');
    $this->load->view('structure/footer');

}



public function show() {
    $this->load->view('structure/head');
    $this->load->view('structure/header');
    $this->load->view('structure/main-navigation');
    $this->load->view('structure/content');
    $this->load->view('structure/side-bar');
    $this->load->view('structure/footer');


}
```

Now, If I go to the link `www.example.com/projects/tickets`

or to the link `www.example.com/projects/tickets/ticket` the page is displayed as excepted. 
If I switch to the page `www.example.com/projects/tickets/ticket/show` the page is displayed as excepted, but although the js files have the correct path they did not work.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check web page source (ctr+u in firefox f.e.) and see what is inside src.

Answer (score 0):

Man I'm going crazy with that, it all seems right, the only difference I could apreciate between your code and the one I use in my production server is:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/tickets

#Add www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Try this way, it always worked for me. Hope it helps!